# pass data from element component content to component html declaration

Tags: angular

I have successfully implemented drag, rotation, and font-scale into a component. This is the logic I used for drag http://jsfiddle.net/Jjgmz/1/ (implementation of rotation and scale is very similar.)

I've got an app.component.html that looks like this:

```
  <app-text></app-text>
```

app-text is defined in text.component.html:

```
<div id="innerDiv" tabindex="-1" [ngStyle]="{'transform': currentRotation(), 'font-size.px':currentFontSize()}"  class="h unselected noselect"  contenteditable="false" (mousedown)="mousedown($event)" (mouseup)="mouseup($event)" (focusout)="focusout($event)" (blur)="focusout($event)" >
    Hello
  </div>
```

text.component.ts has the currentRotation,currentFontSize,mousedown,mouseup,focusout functions defined. However, only the `#innerDiv` in app-text gets rotated and moved around. The app-text tag element is always at the same place. Check this image:

[image]

My question is, how can I pass the rotation, position values from `innerDiv`, to the app-text element. For example, the final app-text would look something like this:

```
<app-text [ngStyle]="{'transform': currentRotationFromInnerDiv(), 'font-size.px':currentFontSizeFromInnerDiv()}"></app-text>
```

I would like to rotate, move.. app-text instead of `#innerDiv`, but keep the logic for the function in `text.component.ts`

`text.component.ts` has model that looks something like this:

```
data = {
rotation: 20,
offset:{120,400},
font-size:17
}
```

This "data" contains all the relevant info that I would like `app-text` element to use.

Comment: Just take a look at docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) to find multiple ways of communication between elements.

Comment: Thanks. I've used Outputs to pass rotate, offset... to parent div. Data is set correctly.  Unfortunately, my #innerDiv loses focus each time parent is updated. Essentially, focusout always gets fired, when you edit the parent element, making what I want to achieve, impossible.

Comment: You're welcome. If you describe more what you want to achieve, maybe you can get some help here.

Comment: will create a plnkr in a sec.